# Bootstrap jumbotron not adjusting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a full width jumbotron with a background color. For some reason it is staying at the default layout with the gray background. I followed the code from the [bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar), so I don't know whats wrong.

In my index.html

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

        <p>...</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css:

```css
.jumbotron {
    position: relative;
    background: #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Seemed pretty straight forward...guess I was wrong.

Comment: Your css is probably not being imported properly because what you have posted works. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fjo4jcp/)

Comment: Why wouldn't it be importing properly? everything else Ive put in the css works fine...

Comment: seems to be an issue with index.html because when I put the code in application.html it works fine.

Comment: David it was just a guess with the given code sample

Answer (score 0):

**DavidK**, Hi there.
Here is a simple demo for you.
Using both ways to display the Jumbotron.

If you have a issue, and your custom css is not below the Bootstrap css link, then that could be your issue.

**Use the FULL PAGE view  to see it.**

Or use this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AngularJR/susoyfmp/)**.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}    
.block {
  height: 200px;
}  

.jumbotron {
    background: #ff0000;
    min-height: 25vh;
}    
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>
        
 <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container bg-primary block">
    ...
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container col-lg-12 spacer"></div>        
        
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>...</p>  
</div>
        
        
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```